# Are all goddesses part of Sati Devi?

Tags: sati-goddess

Is it true that all goddesses (e.g. Ambe, Vaishnodevi and other goddesses) are actually body parts of Sati Devi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Sati's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_%28goddess%29) Wikipedia page-

> Daksha once organized a grand yajna to which all the gods were
>   invited, with the exception of Sati and Shiva.
>
> Sati goes there uninvited without Shiva. Sati was received coldly by
>   her father.  Every passing moment made it clearer to Sati that her
>   father was entirely incapable of appreciating the many excellent
>   qualities of her husband. The realization then came to Sati that this
>   abuse was being heaped on Shiva only because he had wed her; she was
>   the cause of this dishonor to her husband. She was consumed by rage
>   against her father and loathing for his mentality. Calling up a prayer
>   that she may, in a future birth, be born the daughter of a father whom
>   she could respect, Sati invoked her yogic powers or yogic Agni which
>   was attained by her due to severe devotion or puja done by her and
>   immolated herself.
>
> - According to some traditions, it is believed that an angry Shiva performed the fearsome and awe-inspiring Tandava dance with Sati's
>     charred body on his shoulders. During this dance, Sati's body came
>     apart and the pieces fell at different places on earth.
> - According to another version, Shiva placed Sati's body on his shoulder and ran about the world, crazed with grief. The Gods called 
>     upon the god Vishnu to restore Shiva to normalcy and calm. Vishnu used
>     his Sudarshana Chakra to dismember Sati's lifeless body, following 
>     which Shiva regained his equanimity.
>
> Both versions state that Sati's  body was thus dismembered into 51
>   pieces which fell on earth at  various places. Several different
>   listings of these 51 holy places,  known as [Shakti Peethas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakti_Peethas), are
>   available; some of these places have  become major centers of
>   pilgrimage as they are held by the  Goddess-oriented Shakta sect to be
>   particularly holy. Besides 51 main  Shakti pethas, some small peethas
>   like Bindudham have also in  existence which are due to Sati's fallen
>   blood drops.

But three Pindi's of Veshno Devis is out of this 51 Shakti Peethas. Even there is contradictions in this counts in all stories.

From [Vaishno Devi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishno_Devi) Wikipedia page

> Vaishno devi is one of 108 shakti peetha, the story of Vaishno Devi is
>   found in Chandi uppurana. When Vishnu Bhagwan cuts Sati Maa's body
>   into 108 peethas then 52 body parts fell onto earth atmosphere and
>   rest of the 56 fell on other planets. Out of which the "Blessing Hand"
>   of Goddess Sati had fallen on "Planet Venus" or Shukra.

From the same Veshno devi page its is told that Three Pindi's are Made by three Goddess ( Shakti, Sarasvati and lakshmi). So other goddess are not made by part of Sati's body  but this Shakti peetha's are. And the girl Kumari  made of Parvati's physical appearance, soul of "Lakshmi" and Goddess of knowledge, Saraswati. Which is know as Veshno Devi in Bhairav Katha.

Comment: did the sati practice originate from here ?

Answer (score 2):

No. All are not body parts of Devi Sati. It is only the Satipeethas that are known to have Sati's body parts. The number and locations also vary from one tantra to another, the range being four (in Ppranatoshini Tanta) to 51(Peethanirnaya Tantra).The body parts mentioned also vary in different scriptures.

Also, there are Upapeethas that contain the ornaments or clothes etc of Devi Sati.

And there are siddha peethas.

In India, there are hundreds of Devi temples.Among them maximumm Satipeetha containing the body parts are at best 51.
(Ref:Shastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das, vol 1, chapter 6.